# After installing Ubuntu, Windows is booting directly! Grub menu not shown

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub4dos

I Ubuntu on a partition in my 1TB laptop, keeping the Windows partition untouched. I don't understand why Windows boots directly while my friend's laptop show option to boot either Windows or ubuntu.

Comment: I had to add this question because no one is answering my previous question.

Comment: There's not much different than we could say from what is provided on the official Ubuntu download page.  There's a link to these instructions: [Installation guide](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop)  Please follow the instructions there (that link contains a step-by-step guide with pictures.  It wouldn't change much for us to say this to you again. Tell us the specific steps that you performed and the specific error that you are getting if it doesn't work.  The most important information is the **messages on the screen** when you try to boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what i would suggest per what you posted:

open gparted and create a /boot partition greater than 200MB at the beginning of sda

or

reinstall ubuntu and do it during the drive partitioning stage. towards the end of the installation make sure that grub is installed to the master boot record.

#### here are two links that may help you further

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#BIOS-Boot_or_EFI_partition_.28required_on_GPT_disks.29

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative#Create_a_partition_table